# Replace empty lines in one file with lines from another file

Tags: bash, shell, find, csv, replace

I have **file1.csv**

```
"word 1"
""
"word 3"
""
"word 5"
"word 6"
```

and **file2.csv**

```
"replacement text 1"
"replacement text 2"
"replacement text 3"
"replacement text 4"
"replacement text 5"
"replacement text 6"
```

I'm looking for a command that checks where there are empty lines (or lines with "") in file1 and then replaces them with the contents of file2.

The **output.csv** should be

```
"word 1"
"replacement text 2"
"word 3"
"replacement text 4"
"word 5"
"word 6"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another `awk` alternative:

```
awk '{getline other < "file2.csv"}
     $0 == "\"\"" {$0 = other}
     {print}' file1.csv > output.csv
```

Or `paste` + `sed`:

```
paste -d '\n' file1.csv file2.csv| sed 'N;s/^""\n//;s/\n.*//' > output.csv
```

If `file2.csv` doesn't have enough lines to satisfy all `""` lines of `file1.csv`, with the `awk` one, it will reuse the last line of `file2.csv` while with the `paste`+`sed` one, you'll get empty lines. You'll also get extra empty lines there if `file2.csv` has more lines than `file1.csv`.

Answer (score 5):

This is assuming that the files have the same number of lines:  Using `paste` to create a CSV record stream with the fields from the first file as the first header-less column and the fields from the second file as the second header-less column:

```bash
$ paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv
"word 1","replacement text 1"
"","replacement text 2"
"word 3","replacement text 3"
"","replacement text 4"
"word 5","replacement text 5"
"word 6","replacement text 6"
```

We may then use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to update the first field with the values from the second field if the first field is empty:

```bash
$ paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv| mlr --csv -N put 'is_empty($1) { $1 = $2 }'
word 1,replacement text 1
replacement text 2,replacement text 2
word 3,replacement text 3
replacement text 4,replacement text 4
word 5,replacement text 5
word 6,replacement text 6
```

The `is_empty()` test will be true for any field that is empty, regardless of whether it was quoted or not in the input.

We may then cut (extract) the first field:

```bash
$ paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv| mlr --csv -N put 'is_empty($1) { $1 = $2 }' then cut -f 1
word 1
replacement text 2
word 3
replacement text 4
word 5
word 6
```

Miller will only quote fields that actually need quoting.  To force Miller to quote all output fields, use `--quote-all`:

```bash
$ paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv| mlr --csv -N --quote-all put 'is_empty($1) { $1 = $2 }' then cut -f 1
"word 1"
"replacement text 2"
"word 3"
"replacement text 4"
"word 5"
"word 6"
```

You can definitely do something similar with `awk`, but remember that `awk` is not CSV-aware, will treat the double quotes as literal text, and will therefore blindly treat each comma as a delimiter, even if they are embedded in properly quoted fields. It also doesn't understand fields with embedded newlines, but our initial assumption already rules these out.

```bash
$ paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv| awk -F , '$1 == "\"\"" { $1 = $2 } { print $1 }'
"word 1"
"replacement text 2"
"word 3"
"replacement text 4"
"word 5"
"word 6"
```

Comment: What is ‘Miller’? (Whatever it is, it doesn't seem to be installed on any of the Unix boxes I have access to…)

Comment: This is a very good tool. See https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @gidds It's a tool for processing various types of structured data in different ways. I added a link in the answer and Prabhjot mentioned in a previous comment too. I would be surprised to see it installed by default, yes, but it's common to install tools that you need to use, just like one might install any other type of application that is necessary for completing a task.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR == FNR    { a[FNR] = $1; next };
           $1 == "\"\"" { $1 = a[FNR] };
           1' file2.csv file1.csv 
"word 1"
"replacement text 2"
"word 3"
"replacement text 4"
"word 5"
"word 6"
```

This reads in file2.csv and stores column 1 of each line in an array.

Then it reads in file1.csv and, if column 1 is just a pair of double-quotes (i.e. "empty"), replaces column one with the appropriate element of the array (`FNR`, or the current line number of the current file).  Then it prints the current line, whether it has been changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using `csvsql`:

```
$ paste -d, file1 file2 |\
> csvsql -H --query 'SELECT CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN a ELSE b END as output from STDIN' |\
> csvformat -K 1 -U1
"word 1"
"replacement text 2"
"word 3"
"replacement text 4"
"word 5"
"word 6"
```

First `csv` stream is created by `paste` command.

`csvsql` uses `sqlite` dialect. `-H` is used because files are headerless. `-H` sets name of first and second fields to `a` and `b` respectively. Thereafter `CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN a ELSE b END` prints first field when first field is not empty and second filed otherwise. And adding header `output` as we specified.

`csvformat` is used to format output. `-K 1` deletes first record ( header added as `output` in last command). `-U 1` quoting style to quote all.

Answer (score 0):

The following Perl script assumes the original input (`file1.csv`) is stdin, and the replacement files are passed as command-line arguments.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<STDIN>) {
  $_ = <> if /^("")?$/;
  print;
}
```

For example, any of these:

```
$ cat file1.csv | perl this-script.pl file2.csv
$ <file1.csv | perl this-script.pl file2.csv
$ ./this-script.pl file2.csv <file1.csv
```

Or, as a one liner:

```
$ perl -e 'while (<STDIN>) { $_ = <> if /^("")?$/; print }' <file1.csv file2.csv
```